# Autohide rows when there is no query in search box

Tags: javascript, html, css, row, hide

I am totally new to the java coding. I have a list of accounts which I use to show up the right collectors (more than 5000 rows). I have have converted it into a HTML webpage using some online help.

Now I want that when there is no query in search box there should not be any results in below table only headers should appear. As soon as I start typing any customer name and if there are any matches, that should show up and as soon as i delete the query the list should disappear.

Below is the code I am using as of now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 26%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="res/logo.jpg" style="width:350px;height:100px;">

<h2><font face="Arial" color="#c11919">Collector Lookup Tool - Test Phase</font></h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for customer names" title="Type in a name">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:20%;">Customer Name</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Collector Name</th>
    <th style="width:15%;">Collector e-mail</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Region</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Telnet</th>
  </tr>
<tr><td>110 Technology LLC</td><td>Abhishek Yadav</td><td>abhishek.yadav@gmail.com</td><td>Americas</td><td>2684227</td></tr>
<tr><td>14 WFIE TV</td><td>Abhishek Yadav</td><td>abhishek.yadav@gmail.com</td><td>Americas</td><td>2684227</td></tr>
<tr><td>2Wire Inc</td><td>Abhishek Yadav</td><td>abhishek.yadav@gmail.com</td><td>Americas</td><td>2684227</td></tr>
<tr><td>3 Phoenix LLC</td><td>Abhishek Yadav</td><td>abhishek.yadav@gmail.com</td><td>Americas</td><td>2684227</td></tr>
<tr><td>3 Sixty Mfg</td><td>Abhishek Yadav</td><td>abhishek.yadav@gmail.com</td><td>Americas</td><td>2684227</td></tr>
<tr><td>3D at Depth LLC</td><td>Abhishek Yadav</td><td>abhishek.yadav@gmail.com</td><td>Americas</td><td>2684227</td></tr>
.
.
.
.
.
.
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the link to the sample file for reference

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_a89TkNd6sCVGRyNzd6UlI0VDA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to hide all of the rows using a class on the table until you detect a change in the box. For example the class might be:

```
.hidden tr+tr{
  display: none;
}
```

all the `tr+tr` is doing is saying all of the `tr`s following a `tr`, this is so we don't hide the header.

Add this class on the table to start, then in the function add a line that looks something like:

```
if(filter == ''){
    table.classList.add("hidden");
} else {
    table.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

This will then hide things when there's no input and unhide it once there is something in the box.

Comment: Thanks Don for your answer. I am sorry I am a novice in coding stuff. Could you please apply your solution in my code above or the html in the link given below and share with me at prateekvishwas22@gmail.com?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_a89TkNd6sCVGRyNzd6UlI0VDA/view

Comment: I'm not going to do the work for you, I've explained well enough how to get it in there. You're not going to learn if people do it for you, just add it places and think about where it would make sense to happen. If you have questions about what any of the code is doing I'd be happy to explain.

Comment: Thank you Don. I'll get back to you in case I need further help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it complete the complete class code?

.hidden tr+tr{
  display: none;
}

Don't I need anything or myTable before .hidden....?

Comment: you could use `#myTable.hidden tr+tr` and be more verbose, but the way I posted it will work, and will work on any table with the hidden class if you add another table to the page. Be sure to *not* put a space between `#myTable` and `.hidden` though otherwise you'll be selecting children of `#myTable` which have the class `hidden` and not the element with id `myTable` that also has the class `hidden`